# Calculate the divisor of the differential $dx/y$ on $C$ and use the result to show that $C$ has genus $g$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

**(Silverman's The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves Exercise 2.14)** For this exercise we assume that char K $\neq 2$. Let $f(x)\in K[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $d\geq 1$ with nonzero discriminant, let $C_0/K$ be the affine curve given by the equation
$$C_0 : y^2=f(x)=a_0x^d+a_1x^{d-1}+\dots+a_{d-1}x+a_d$$
and let $g$ be the unique integer satisfying $d-3<2g\leq d-1$.

(a) Let $C$ be the closure of the image of $C_0$ via the map
$$ [1,x,x^2,\dots,x^{g-1},y] : C_0\to \mathbb{P}^{g+2}$$
Prove that $C$ is smooth and that $C\cap \{X_0\neq 0\}$ is isomorphic to $C_0$. The curve $C$ is called a ***hyperelliptic curve***.

> **I have already proved this part by I wanted to provide it since (b) does refer to it.**

(b) Let
$$
f^*(v)=v^{2g+2}f(1/v)=
\begin{cases}
a_0+a_1v+\dots+a_{d-1}v^{d-1}+a_dv^d & \text{ if $d$ is even} \\
a_0v+a_1v^2+\dots+a_{d-1}v^{d}+a_dv^{d+1} & \text{ if $d$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
Show that $C$ consists of two affine pieces
$$ C_0 : y^2=f(x) 
\hspace{1cm} \text{ and } \hspace{1cm}
C_1:w^2=f^*(v) $$
"glued together" via the maps
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
C_0 & \to C_1 \\
(x,y) & \mapsto (1/x,y/x^{g+1})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
C_1 & \to C_0 \\
(v,w) & \mapsto (1/v,w/v^{g+1})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

> Proof of (b): Using the dehomogenization in (a), we have already shown
> that $C$ consists of $C_0$ and $C_1$. Note that $C_0$ contains all but
> one or two points of $C$, but these points were shown to be in $C_1$.
> Thus these are the only two necessary pieces. What is left to show is
> "gluing" portion.
>
> We need only consider points on $C$ that are on both the affine
> part of $C_0$ (where $X_0\neq 0$) and the affine part of $C_1$ (where
> $X_{g+1}\neq 0$). Now, using the coordinates of $C_0$, we see that
> $X_{g+1}=x^{g+1}$. Thus $$ v
> =\dfrac{X_g}{X_{g+1}}
> =\dfrac{x^g}{x^{g+1}}
> =\dfrac{1}{x} $$ Also $$ u
> =\dfrac{X_{g+2}}{X_{g+1}}
> =\dfrac{x^{g+2}}{x^{g+1}}
> =\dfrac{y}{x^{g+1}} $$ Thus the gluing map $C_0\to C_1$ is  $$(x,y)\mapsto (1/x,y/x^{g+1})$$
>
> Now let's look at the other direction. Recall that using the
> coordinates of $C_1$, we have $X_0=v^{g+1}$. Thus $$ x
> =\dfrac{X_1}{X_0}
> =\dfrac{v^g}{v^{g+1}}
> =\dfrac{1}{v} $$ and $$ y
> =\dfrac{X_{g+2}}{X_0}
> =\dfrac{v^{g+2}}{v^{g+1}}
> =\dfrac{u}{v^{g+1}} $$ Thus the gluing map $C_1\to C_2$ is  $$ (v,u)\mapsto (1/v,u/v^{g+1}) $$

> ** My question is why $\dfrac{x^{g+2}}{x^{g+1}}=\dfrac{y}{x^{g+1}}$? And similarly, $\dfrac{v^{g+2}}{v^{g+1}}=\dfrac{u}{v^{g+1}}$? **

(c) Calculate the divisor of the differential $dx/y$ on $C$ and use the result to show that $C$ has genus $g$. Check your answer by applying Hurwitz's formula **(II.5.9)** to the map $[1,x] : C \to \mathbb{P}^1$. (Note that Exercise 2.7 does not apply, since $C\not\subset \mathbb{P}^2$).

> ** For (c), I am not sure how to calculate the divisor of the differential. Do I find $dx/y$ by taking the derivative of the mappings in (b)?

(d) Find a basis for the holomorphic differentials on $C$. (Hint: Consider the set of differential forms $\{x^i dx/y : i=0,1,2,\dots.\}$ How many elements in this set are holomorphic?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135453/discussion-on-question-by-username-unknown-calculate-the-divisor-of-the-differen).

Answer (score 1):

(b) Since $C$ is defined with the map
$$ 
[1,x,\dots,x^{g-1},y] :  C_0 \to \mathbb{P}^{g+2} 
$$
and since $K$ is algebraically closed,
$\dfrac{x^{g+2}}{x^{g+1}}=\dfrac{y}{x^{g+1}}$ and  $\dfrac{v^{g+2}}{v^{g+1}}=\dfrac{w}{v^{g+1}}$

(c) First, let's compute $\,dx/y$. Using the maps from (b), we have
$v=\dfrac{1}{x}$ and $w=\dfrac{y}{x^{g+1}}$

Let's rewrite this equations so that we have $x$ and $y$ equal to functions of $u$, and $w$.
$x=\dfrac{1}{v}$ and $y=\dfrac{w}{v^{g+1}}$

We can differentiate the first equation and get: $\,dx=-\dfrac{1}{v^2}\,dv$.
Hence $$\dfrac{\,dx}{y}=-\dfrac{v^{g-1}}{w}\,dv$$
Recall that a divisor is a formal $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of points. The divisor of a differential is of the form $\sum_i n_iP_i$ where the $P_i$ are the points at which the differential has a zero or pole, and $n_i$ is the order of zero or pole.

Since the discriminant is nonzero (i.e. $f$ is separable), we have $d$ distinct roots. Also since $\,dx=-\dfrac{1}{v^2}\,dv$, we have a double poles at $(0,1)$ at $(0,-1)$.
Hence the divisor of the differential is
$$div(\,dx/y)=P_1+P_2+\dots+P_d-2(0,1)-2(0,-1)$$

What remains to do is actually check that the genus of $C$ is $g$ via Hurtwiz's formula. Let's defined the map $\pi=[1,x]:C\to\mathbb{P}^1$, with genuses $g_1$ and $g_2$ respectively. By Hurtwiz's Formula,
$$2g_1-2=\deg(\pi)(2g_2-2)+\sum\limits_{P\in C} (e_\pi(P)-1)$$
Recall that the genus of the projective line is $0$, and $\deg(\pi)=2$. So,
$$2g_1-2=-4+\sum\limits_{P\in C} (e_\pi(P)-1)$$
Associated to $C$ is a double cover $\pi:C\to \mathbb{P}^1$ of the projective line. This cover has $2g+2$ ramification points. Hence
\begin{gather*}
2g_1-2=-4+(2g+2) \\
2g_1-2=2g-2 \\
g_1=g
\end{gather*}
Hence $C$ has genus $g$.

(d) Let $\{x^i\,dx/y | i=0,\dots,g-1\}$. (Note that $0\leq i\leq g-1$ is due to the fact that $K$ is algebraically closed.) To show that this is a suitable basis for holomorphic differentials on $C$. It is enough to show that $x^i\,dx/y$ is holomorphic. i.e. We need to compute the divisor of $x^i\,dx/y$ and show that it has no poles.

Let's begin with the cases where $i=0$. Recall that the equation of $C$ is $y^2=f(x)$. So when we differentiate it, we have the relation
$$2y\,dy=f'(x)\,dx  \iff  \dfrac{\,dx}{y}=\dfrac{\,dy}{f'(x)} $$
Since $C$ is nonsingular, then $y$ and $f'(x)$ can't both vanish. Hence $\,dx/y$ is holomorphic.

Since $x^i$ will just yield zeroes (and not poles), we can use the same argument above when $0<i\leq g-1$. Hence
$$\{x^i\,dx/y | i=0,\dots,g-1\}$$
is the basis for the holomorphic differentials on $C$.